# Sound bytes for iPhone apps

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audio, audiotoolbox

Can someone suggest where I can browse and download various sound bytes for iPhone applications? I need to add various ticks and swooping sounds to my app.

Any info would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use any mp3 or sound file supported [wav]

so find sound effects like in this site:

[Absolute Sound Effects Archive](http://www.grsites.com/archive/sounds/)

then use your media Player for simple sound playing

follow this  [tutorial for playing your sound effects](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/implementing-sound-effect-in-iphone/)

good luck!

Comment: I have to give the answer to you for providing the extra tutorial. I like freesound.org better however...

Answer (score 1):

Try http://www.freesound.org - lots of small sound effects under Creative Commons license.